# SQL indexing in a large table with inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, indexing, inner-join

We have a large table (16 mil and counting). 
The structure of the table is:

**id_PIT |
id_instrument |
id_data_label |
date |
value |
note (nullable)**

Most often used request is:

We take all dates in one table:

```
INSERT INTO #DTS
SELECT DISTINCT
date DT
FROM Point_in_time
WHERE date BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
```

Then we do:

```
INSERT INTO #PIT
SELECT Value V, date D
FROM Point_in_time
WHERE id_instrument = @idInstrument
AND id_data_label = @idDataLable
AND date BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -6, @startDate) AND @endDate
```

The last query is we do inner join on these two tables like this:

```
SELECT 
#DTS.DT D,
#PIT.V V
FROM #DTS
left outer JOIN #PIT ON
(SELECT MAX(#PIT.D)
FROM #PIT
WHERE #DTS.DT >= #PIT.D) = #PIT.D
WHERE #DTS.DT BETWEEN @startDate and @endDate
ORDER BY #DTS.DT
```

so whats the problem.. it takes too long (like 50 seconds) and it is holding us back in our development. We tried a couple of different indexes on Point_in_time mostly we thought that index (id_data_label,id_instrument) would help but id doesnt.

Can anyone help us with this? What index should we use or is there any other way we can optimize our database.

Comment: Why is this tagged as `mysql` and `sql-server`?

Comment: Is the answer supposed to work on both MySQL and SQL Server. Left outer join is not an inner join. Why do you need to join the table with itself - what are you trying to do? Please give us some sample data and expected result.

Comment: your final query is using a corelated subquery - the subquery in the JOIN clause is using fields from the outer/parent query, which means that for EVERY row considered for joining, the subquery will be executed. that means your "one" query is actually 1 + x queries, where x is the number of rows in #dts that pass the `where` filter.

Comment: Thank you Marc B. Could you please help me to solve this?